# React app wont update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, airtable

I am making a to-do app using React JS and Airtable, which has a convienent API for managing data. I am new to React, and I have limited experience with JS and APIs, but I have figured out most of the stuff I need to do.

My question is mostly React based, as I can't seem to get my app to automatically refresh. I have read about React lifecycles and using `this.setState()` to schedule an update, but I keep missing something.

Here is a stripped-down version where I try to delete an item.

```
class App extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      records: []
    };

    this.fetchAirtable = this.fetchAirtable.bind(this);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(props);
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);   
  }    

  deleteItem(record){
    console.log("Trashing", record.fields["Title"]);
    base(table).destroy(record.id, (err, deletedRecord) => {
      if (err) { console.error(err);  return  }
    })

    this.setState({record});   
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchAirtable()
  }

  async fetchAirtable() {
    const records = await base(table).select().all()
      .then( r => {return r});
    this.setState({records});
  }

  render() {
    var {records} = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {records.map(record => 
          <ul  id="tasks" key={record.id} >
            <div id="due" className="task-field">
              { record.fields["Due Date"] }
              <img src={trash}
                   className="trashcan"
                   alt="trash"
                   onClick={(e) => this.deleteItem(record, e)}
                />
             </div>
           </ul>
         )}
       </div>
     )
   }    
}
```

Obviously this isn't the whole project, but the idea is that when you click the image of the trashcan, it deletes the item. That works great, and the item is deleted from the Airtable database. The issue is that it does not get removed from the app.

Any help you would be appreciated!

PS. Here is my [Github](https://github.com/SethForrest/homework/tree/PHD_homework/PHD/airtable-react-master) directory with this project if you need it.

Edit 1:  Thanks to @ManavM I updated `deleteItem()`. It seems to be updating the record, but I am still not getting my table to refresh.

```
  deleteItem(record){
    base(table).destroy(record.id, (err, deletedRecord) => {
      if (err) { console.error(err);  return  }
    })

    this.fetchAirtable
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the code

```
 async deleteItem(record){
    console.log("Trashing", record.fields["Title"]);
    base(table).destroy(record.id, (err, deletedRecord) => {
      if (err) { console.error(err);  return  }
      await this.fetchAirtable();
    })

    this.setState({record});   
  }
```

Firstly you're setting `{record: record}` where the `record` key does not exist.

What you need to do is to fetch the modified `base(table)` after you have completed destroying the record.

Another, more efficient way would be to simultaneously modify your state according to the action you just performed. That is

```
const modifiedRecords = records.filter(rcd => rcd.id !== record.id;);
this.setState({records: modifiedRecords});
```

Comment: So I I added this to the `deleteItem()` function, and it _seems_ to update the state, but it still does not reload the table.  `base(table).select().all().then( r => this.setState )  `

Comment: try logging the stte to see if this is modifying the state as needed. If not you need to try one of the above solutions to see if they solve it. If the state is getting updated but not causing a re-render, you can try using this.forceUpdate() after the state is set.

Comment: I would suggest simply calling `fetchAirtable()` after deleting the record (ie, in the callback for the `destroy()` function.

Comment: replaced that with `this.fetchAirtable` ( see OP ) and it is still not refreshing. Could the probelm be somewhere else? perhaps I need some other lifecycle function?

Comment: You see your `destroy()` function is asynchrouous which means the change you have made **might**(as fetchTable is also async) not work. Check the edit on the code in the answer

Comment: I appreciate your help. It still isnt dynamically updating my list, and unfortunately, that is the main part of my project

Answer (score -1):

I've checked with the code, have you noticed that in your render() function you've given `var {records} = this.state` where it must be `var records = this.state.records` there is no need for {} when its not inside the return.

And if you're sure the state gets updated and yet the render function does not rerender the table, then you should try `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` and return true in that if changes are made to the new state ( Which still has to be rendered ).

Comment: Wrong answer, this is called  Object Destructuring https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring

Comment: I thought it was an issue with rendering the component after updating the state, atleast that is what I understood from _Thanks to @ManavM I updated deleteItem(). It seems to be updating the record, but I am still not getting my table to refresh._ . Sorry if i've made any mistake.

Comment: What i wanted to point out is `var {records} = this.state` and `var records = this.state.records` are the same thing

Comment: Oh. Since he mentioned he was new to react that is not how it hit me. Sorry anways.